# Why do I get a view error when enumerating a Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Why do I get a "view" error:

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame()
ndf['Signals'] = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
signals_diff = ndf.Signals.diff()
ndf['Revals'] = [101,102,105,104,105,106,107,108,109,109]
ndf['Entry'] = 0
for i,element in enumerate(signals_diff):
    if (i==0):
        ndf.iloc[i]['Entry'] = ndf.iloc[i]['Revals']
    elif (element == 0):
            ndf.iloc[i]['Entry'] = ndf.iloc[i - 1]['Entry']
    else:
        ndf.iloc[i]['Entry'] = ndf.iloc[i]['Revals']
```

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> ndf.iloc[i]['Entry'] = ndf.iloc[i]['Revals']

Answer (score 1):

instead of `iloc` use `loc`:

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame()
ndf['Signals'] = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
signals_diff = ndf.Signals.diff()
ndf['Revals'] = [101,102,105,104,105,106,107,108,109,109]
ndf['Entry'] = 0
for i,element in enumerate(signals_diff):
    if (i==0):
        ndf.loc[i,'Entry'] = ndf.loc[i,'Revals']
    elif (element == 0):
            ndf.loc[i,'Entry'] = ndf.loc[i - 1,'Entry']
    else:
        ndf.loc[i,'Entry'] = ndf.loc[i,'Revals']
```

This will solve the problem but when assigning, the index should be same. So because of the index thing you might not be able to get the expected result.

Comment: This solution does give me the correct answer, BUT I need to run this on a huge Dataframe (3 million+ rows). Is there anyway to make this loop much faster?

Comment: @ManInMoon: Quang Hong answer will help then.

Answer (score 0):

Do not chain indexes like `ndf.iloc[i]['Entry']` when trying to assign something. See [why does that not work](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing).

That said, your code can be rewrite as:

```
ndf['Entry'] = ndf['Revals'].where(signals_diff != 0).ffill()
```

Output:

```
   Signals  Revals  Entry
0        1     101  101.0
1        1     102  101.0
2        1     105  101.0
3        1     104  101.0
4        1     105  101.0
5        0     106  106.0
6        0     107  106.0
7        0     108  106.0
8        0     109  106.0
9        0     109  106.0
```

Comment: Hi Quang - I realise it CAN be written that way, but this is a simple example. I will need to be much more complex and need an iterative solution - unfortunately

Comment: @ManInMoon then see pygirl's solution. In general, I would avoid looping. have a look at things like `groupby().shift()`  for this purpose. But if you are certain that looping is unavoidable, then go ahead with looping.

Comment: I will need to change "Entry" based on a derivative of Revals later on

Comment: If you can't communicate exactly what you are trying to do and what you are expecting, then looping is your safest bet...

Comment: Vector version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66320221/how-can-i-avoid-loop-in-this-incomplete-vector-solution

Comment: HI, I created a better explained version of my question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66332408/how-can-i-get-a-vector-to-hold-previous-value-in-the-code

Answer (score 0):

Let us keep using the `index` position slice with `get_indexer`

```
for i,element in enumerate(signals_diff):
    
    if (i==0):
        ndf.iloc[i,ndf.columns.get_indexer(['Entry'])] = ndf.iloc[i,ndf.columns.get_indexer(['Revals'])]
    elif (element == 0):
            ndf.iloc[i,ndf.columns.get_indexer(['Entry'])] = ndf.iloc[i - 1,ndf.columns.get_indexer(['Entry'])]
    else:
        ndf.iloc[i,ndf.columns.get_indexer(['Entry'])] = ndf.iloc[i,ndf.columns.get_indexer(['Revals'])]
```