# How can I avoid loop in this incomplete vector solution

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

**I HAVE CLOSED THIS QUESTION AND STARTED A NEW ONE AS I DIDN'T EXPLAIN IT CORECTLY**

[How can I get a vector to hold previous value in the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66332408/how-can-i-get-a-vector-to-hold-previous-value-in-the-code)

How can I avoid using a loop in this situation where ''Entry' needs to be reset to 'Reval' when 'NeewSignal' is set to 0?

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame()
ndf['Signals'] = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
signals_diff = ndf.Signals.diff()
ndf['Revals'] = [101,102,105,104,105,106,107,108,109,109]
ndf['Entry'] = ndf.Revals.where(signals_diff != 0).ffill()
ndf['EntrySignal'] = ndf.Signals.where(signals_diff != 0).ffill()
ndf['Profit'] = (ndf.Revals - ndf.Entry) * ndf.EntrySignal
ndf['ProfitPct'] = ndf.Profit/ndf.Revals
ndf['NewSignals'] = ndf.Signals.where(ndf.ProfitPct < 0.001, other=0)
```

BUT I need to reset `'Entry'` to `'Reval'` when `'NewSignal' == 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `np.where()` function:

```
ndf.assign(Entry=lambda x: np.where(x['NewSignals'] == 0, x['Revals'], x['Entry']))
```

**Output**

```
    Signals Revals  Entry   EntrySignal Profit  ProfitPct            NewSignals
0   1       101     101.0   1.0         0.0     0.0                  1
1   1       102     102.0   1.0         1.0     0.00980392156862745  0
2   1       105     105.0   1.0         4.0     0.0380952380952381   0
3   1       104     104.0   1.0         3.0     0.028846153846153848 0
4   1       105     105.0   1.0         4.0     0.0380952380952381   0
5   0       106     106.0   0.0         0.0     0.0                  0
6   0       107     107.0   0.0         0.0     0.0                  0
7   0       108     108.0   0.0         0.0     0.0                  0
8   0       109     109.0   0.0         0.0     0.0                  0
9   0       109     109.0   0.0         0.0     0.0                  0
```