# How can I get a vector to hold previous value in the code

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want "NewSignals" to be set to 0 when Profit >= 2 AND stay zero until a change in "Signals"

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame()
ndf['Signals'] = [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1]
signals_diff = ndf.Signals.diff()
ndf['Revals'] = [101,102,105,106,107,106,107,105,109,109,108,107,106]
ndf['Entry'] = ndf.Revals.where(signals_diff != 0).ffill()
ndf['EntrySignal'] = ndf.Signals.where(signals_diff != 0).ffill()
ndf['Profit'] = (ndf.Revals - ndf.Entry) * ndf.EntrySignal
ndf['NewSignals'] = ndf.Signals.where(ndf.Profit < 2.0, other=0)
print (ndf)
```

My wanted output is in WANTNewSignals

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. Just compare Profit and Signals and based on that you can choose what to put in wanted signals. Look at the code below it will serve your purpose i hope.

```
import pandas as pd

ndf = pd.DataFrame()
ndf['Signals'] = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1]
signals_diff = ndf.Signals.diff()
ndf['Revals'] = [101, 102, 105, 106, 107, 106, 107, 105, 109, 109, 108, 107, 106]
ndf['Entry'] = ndf.Revals.where(signals_diff != 0).ffill()
ndf['EntrySignal'] = ndf.Signals.where(signals_diff != 0).ffill()
ndf['Profit'] = (ndf.Revals - ndf.Entry) * ndf.EntrySignal
ndf['NewSignals'] = ndf.Signals.where(ndf.Profit < 2.0, other=0)
print(ndf)

signals = list(ndf['Signals'])
profit = list(ndf['Profit'] )
print(signals)

NewSignals = []
keep_0 = False

for index, value in enumerate(profit):
    if value >= 2:
        NewSignals.append(0)
        keep_0 = True
    else:
        condition = signals[index] == signals[index - 1]
        if keep_0 and condition:
            new_value = 0 if condition else signals[index]
            NewSignals.append(new_value)
        else:
            NewSignals.append(signals[index])
            keep_0 = False

ndf['WantedSignals'] = NewSignals
print(ndf)
```

Comment: Hi, I was looking for a completely vectorised solution. As loop in my case is very slow